# What does mean of using the “{}” keyword in class constructor (Dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm sorry if this sounds like an extremely foolish question but it's really new in Dart and Flutter. In the examples for Flutter, I often see such a constructor:

```
class CalTable extends StatefulWidget {

  // Constructor with initializer ( : )
  CalTable({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CalTableState createState() => _CalTableState();
}
```

I know what {} is it MAP or SET. But what exactly does {} mean here? And why is it used to convey **just one value** Key key ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with maps or sets, it's Dart's way to mark **named parameters**.

In your specific case, `CalTable({Key key})` means you have one parameter by the name of `key`. It's not positional, so you cannot just write `CalTable(yourKey)`. It's named, you'd have to write `CalTable(key: yourKey)`. In addition, unless specified otherwise, all named parameters are optional, so `CalTable()` would be valid too.

That said, I encourage you to update to a recent version of Dart and Flutter because your example is so old, it would not compile in todays versions because of null-safety.

See the [language tour on parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters) to find out more about named parameters.

Comment: Many thanks. I am very inattentive, I could have guessed myself